# If you grapple a creature while staying out of its reach, can it still attack you?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, reach

A [Kraken](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/kraken) is able to grapple up to 10 creatures with its tentacles, the reach for this attack is 30 ft.

> ***Tentacle.*** Melee Weapon Attack: +17 to hit, reach 30 ft., one target. Hit: 20 (3d6 + 10) bludgeoning damage, and the target is grappled (escape DC 18). Until this grapple ends, the target is restrained. The kraken has ten tentacles, each of which can grapple one target.

Can a creature with a reach of 5 ft. which is grappled 30 ft. away from the Krakens position attack it with a melee weapon attack? It would make sense, that one could aim for the grappling tentacle, but is it RAW/RAI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a froghemoth's grapple attack prevent characters attacking it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113430)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yes, seems like it. Sorry, didn't see it

Comment: No trouble at all! That's why we have a whole community of people: if one person doesn't find something, there's a good chance someone else will. And now this post enriches the web of phrasing for the question, making it easier to find.

Answer (score -1):

As a DM, I would almost treat these as having a separate AC and healthbar, since you are attacking the grappling tentacle and not attacking the creature as a whole. That being said, I would also rule that the creature takes damage from this, too, because it generally *hurts* when a limb is cut-off.

The tentacle would have a lower AC because it is restricted from moving, in a certain manner, by the fact that it still has to maintain a grapple on you.

Note that you would be attacking at Disadvantage as per being Restrained.